# How I can validate input on smart table(ng2-smart-table)?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular2-services

I would like to know how I can validate input on ng2-smart-table  (Angular2).
I can't find any documentation related to this article.
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't have in documentation as they have not implemented it suggestions were going on for the validation but no progress on the same. As the developer have stopped working on it and switched to angular4-material-table which is much more configurable then this one you can check that on the following link.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-smart-table-custom

So there is no direct way to do a validation. You can check the following discussion on the github for further understanding.

https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/issues/6

https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/issues/420

Comment: They have really not added it in the library I had included the same in my project but no use in the end I have to switched to my custom table. Else I had to modify the library own function and make it possible that would had been a lengthy task. Any chance of an upvote?